# bash script: use command output to dynamically create menu and arrays?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a script to run a command and take that output and use it to create a menu dynamically. I also need to access parts of each output line for specific values.

I am using the command:

```
lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial,size | grep "sd"
```

output:

```
sda   600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX872 512G
sdb   600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf34 127G
```

I need to create a menu that looks like:

```
Available Drives:
1) sda   600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX872 512G
2) sdb   600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf34 127G
Please select a drive:
```

(note: there can be any number of drives, this menu would be constructed dynamically from the available drives array)

When the user selects the menu number I need to be able to access the drive id (sdb) and drive serial number (600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf34) for the selected drive.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read command output line by line into array ${lines [@]}
# Bash 3.x: use the following instead:
#   IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra lines < <(lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial,size | grep "sd")
readarray -t lines < <(lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial,size | grep "sd")

# Prompt the user to select one of the lines.
echo "Please select a drive:"
select choice in "${lines[@]}"; do
  [[ -n $choice ]] || { echo "Invalid choice. Please try again." >&2; continue; }
  break # valid choice was made; exit prompt.
done

# Split the chosen line into ID and serial number.
read -r id sn unused <<<"$choice"

echo "id: [$id]; s/n: [$sn]"
```

---

As for what you tried: using an unquoted command substitution (`$(...)`) inside an array constructor (`( ... )`) makes the tokens in the command's output subject to *word splitting* and *globbing*, which means that, by default, each whitespace-separated token becomes its own array element, and may expand to matching filenames.

Filling arrays in this manner is fragile, and even though you can fix that by setting `IFS` and turning off globbing (`set -f`), the better approach is to use `readarray -t` (Bash v4+) or `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra` (Bash v3.x) with a process substitution to fill an array with the (unmodified) lines output by a command.

Comment: Oh, awesome, this was very close to the solution i managed to come up with, and even better.  Many many thanks!

Comment: also, thanks for the additional details, information, and comments on other solutions, they were quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to untangle the issue in an elegant way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Dynamic Menu Function
createmenu () {
    select selected_option; do # in "$@" is the default
        if [ 1 -le "$REPLY" ] && [ "$REPLY" -le $(($#)) ]; then
            break;
        else
            echo "Please make a vaild selection (1-$#)."
        fi
    done
}

declare -a drives=();
# Load Menu by Line of Returned Command
mapfile -t drives < <(lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial,size | grep "sd");
# Display Menu and Prompt for Input
echo "Available Drives (Please select one):";
createmenu "${drives[@]}"
# Split Selected Option into Array and Display
drive=($(echo "${selected_option}"));
echo "Drive Id: ${drive[0]}";
echo "Serial Number: ${drive[1]}";
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like the following

```
#!/bin/bash

# define an array
declare -a obj

# capture the current IFS
cIFS=$IFS

# change IFS to something else
IFS=:

# assign & format output from lsblk 
obj=( $(lsblk --nodeps --no name,serial,size) )

# generate a menu system
select item from ${obj[@]}; do
  if  [ -n ${item} ]; then
    echo "Invalid selection"
    continue
  else
    selection=${item}
    break
  fi
done

# reset the IFS
IFS=${cIFS}
```

That should be a bit more portable with less dependencies such as readarray which isn't available on some systems

Comment: If someone could change my formatting for code blocks that would be cool

Comment: Arrays aren't portable altogether (not supported by the POSIX shell spec.), so you may as well utilize all that Bash has to offer. While setting `IFS` before using `( $(...) )` is an improvement, it's still a practice to avoid in general. As for `readarray`: on older Bash versions, use `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra`.

Comment: To be more specific: both `readarray` and `read` are Bash _builtins_, so their availability doesn't vary by _platform_, only by _Bash version_: `readarray` (and its synonym `mapfile`) was introduced in Bash 4.0.

Comment: @mklement0 so on embedded busybox systems it is available?

Comment: @jas: Wikipedia tells me that the shell built into busybox is [ash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_shell). Ash doesn't support arrays altogether, from what I can tell, so the availability of `readarray` is a moot point.
If you want true portability, use only POSIX-compliant shell-language features - which also rules out the use of arrays.

Comment: @mklement0 turns out i need to modify the script for an older system that doesn't have readarray or mapfile.

How do I adapt your:
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra

to get and array of lines from:
($(lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial,size | grep "sd"))

many many thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaJarman: The full command is `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra lines < <(lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial,size | grep "sd")`.